# Java stream: Collect Stream<int[]> to List<int[]>

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I try to get my head around java streams.

Atm I have this construct which does not work:

```
List<int[]> whiteLists = processes.stream()
              .map(Process::getEventList)
              .forEach(eventList -> eventList.stream()
                      .map(event -> event.getPropertie("whitelist"))
                      .map(propertie -> propertie.getIntArray())
                      .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

---

The hierarchy is:

- Process

  - Event

    - Property

Process::getEventList returns a list of `Event` objects

`event.getPropertie("whitelist")` returns a `Property` objects which hast the method `getIntArray()`

`event.getPropertie()` gives me an int-array.

---

How do I collect these array into a List of arrays?

Thanks!

---

Comment: What is the problem this is unclear ? What does return `event.getPropertie("whitelist")` and what does return `propertie.getIntArray()` ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please give us a minimal and reproducible example. This may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Kayaman gave the correct answer. Not using a FlatMap was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `forEach()` as it takes a `Consumer`, meaning it will consume the stream, but can't return anything (so nothing to collect).

You need [flatMap](https://www.baeldung.com/java-difference-map-and-flatmap) to stream the internal `eventList` as follows

```
List<int[]> whiteLists = processes.stream()
                                  .flatMap(p -> p.getEventList().stream())
                                  .map(event -> event.getPropertie("whitelist"))
                                  .map(propertie -> propertie.getIntArray())
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```